# How to retrive the outer points from shapes or point Collection?

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, graphics

Here I have this point collection,

```
<Polyline Points="568,263,568,262,568,262,568,260,568,260,568,259,568,257,568,257,568,256,567,256,567,256,567,255,567,255,567,255,567,255,567,255,567,254,567,254,566,254,566,254,567,253,566,253,566,253,566,252,566,252,566,251,565,251,565,250,565,250,565,250,565,250,565,250,565,249,564,249,564,249,564,248,564,248" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
<Polyline Points="544,238,545,238,546,238,548,238,549,239,550,239,551,239,551,239,552,239,552,240,553,240,553,240,554,240,554,240,555,241,556,241,556,241,557,241,557,241,557,242,557,242,557,242,558,242,558,242,558,243,558,243,559,243,559,243,559,243,559,244,560,244,560,244,560,244,560,244,561,245,561,245,561,245,561,245,562,245,562,245,562,246,562,246" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
<Polyline Points="544,238,563,247,568,263,544,263,544,238,544,238" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
<Polyline Points="557,244,559,245,560,245,561,245,562,246,562,246,563,247,563,247,563,247,563,248,557,248,557,243,557,243" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
<Polyline Points="520,263,520,262,520,262,520,260,520,260,520,259,520,257,520,257,520,256,521,256,521,256,521,255,521,255,521,255,521,255,521,255,521,254,521,254,522,254,522,254,521,253,522,253,522,253,522,252,522,252,522,251,523,251,523,250,523,250,523,250,523,250,523,250,523,249,524,249,524,249,524,248,524,248" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
<Polyline Points="544,238,543,238,542,238,540,238,539,239,538,239,537,239,537,239,536,239,536,240,535,240,535,240,534,240,534,240,533,241,532,241,532,241,531,241,531,241,531,242,531,242,531,242,530,242,530,242,530,243,530,243,529,243,529,243,529,243,529,244,528,244,528,244,528,244,528,244,527,245,527,245,527,245,527,245,526,245,526,245,526,246,526,246" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
<Polyline Points="544,238,525,247,520,263,544,263,544,238,544,238" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"  />
```

This Point collection form the below shape,

[image]

I need the outer points without the inside shapes. 
I need output image like this [image]

I also tried finding outer points using algorithm.

ref link : [Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan#Pseudocode)
 But i'm not getting the exact result any one guide me . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you share your implementation?

Comment: @John https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/360516/Visual-implementation-of-Grahams-scan-algorithms-d. This project only, i given my point collection and tried.

Comment: Look for "alpha shape"

Comment: It's mentioned here that wikipedia code does not work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25204997/1099716

Comment: Do you need outer points or outer shape?

Comment: @Yola  I need outer points

Comment: How do you define outer? Are these that lies on the convex hull?

Comment: @yola I'm try with convex hull. It is working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This one I got answer.

I merge all the points and using convex hull algorithm , I will get the outer points.

[convex hull algorithm reference Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/775753/A-Convex-Hull-Algorithm-and-its-implementation-in)